# task is skipped even when condition is met

Tags: ansible

There are following three consecutive tasks in a playbook:

```
  - debug:
     msg: "{{ cert_result.stdout }}"
    tags:
     - debug

  - name: Certdir rehash
    shell: "cacertdir_rehash /etc/openldap/cacerts/"
    when: cert_result|int == 1
    tags:
     - carehash

  - debug:
     msg: "{{ cert_result.stdout }}"
    tags:
     - debug
```

I can't explain why the "Certdir rehash" is skipped even if cert_result variable is set to 1

Here output from those three tasks during run:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 24 May 2021  23:11:01 +0200 (0:00:02.514)       0:00:08.004 ************
ok: [192.168.1.110] => {
    "msg": "1"
}

TASK [Certdir rehash] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 24 May 2021  23:11:01 +0200 (0:00:00.156)       0:00:08.160 ************
skipping: [192.168.1.110]

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 24 May 2021  23:11:01 +0200 (0:00:00.156)       0:00:08.317 ************
ok: [192.168.1.110] => {
    "msg": "1"
}
```

Why ansible is skipping this task with `when: cert_result|int == 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `debug` with `cert_result.stdout` but for `when` you are only using `cert_result`. I think you should use the same as below.

```
 - name: Certdir rehash
    shell: "cacertdir_rehash /etc/openldap/cacerts/"
    when: cert_result.stdout|int == 1
    tags:
     - carehash
```

Notice the difference when you used `cert_result.stdout` vs `cert_result`, only the former returned `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

`cert_result` is not an integer, it’s a dictionary containing the property `stdout` which is what you want to typecast. Notice how  you’re calling `cert_result.stdout` in both debug tasks, but *not* in the one conditional task being skipped.

Change your `when` into `cert_result.stdout | int == 1`.